# Laravel multisite with domain mapping

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm attempting to create a multisite in Laravel, so one codebase but with several sites operating from it. Each site will have similar functionality, so can reuse code, but each site will use a different theme - which I imagine would be as simple as having different themes in the views folder and mapping them depending on the domain that the customer has come through.

I want to be able to access Site X from www.sitex.com, Site Y from www.sitey.com etc, while having only one laravel install and not resorting to any vhosts tomfoolery.

Would any of you be so kind as to advise me on a solution, or to point me in the right direction? I've had next to no luck finding anything so far!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your routing is not going to be too complex you could potentially get away with having numerous public folders

```
 laravel
   app
   bootstrap
   sitex.com
   sitey.com
   vendor
```

Then each of your site will be it's own virtualhost with no funky alias rules like so (for security, make sure there is no access to the laravel root dir):

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/laravel/sitex.com"
```

Lastly, you would put a variable in **bootstrap/paths.php** where the public path will be

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../'.preg_match('/\w+.com/',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']),
```

This should work for the majority of deployments even with subdomain routing because bootstrap gets initiated from the index.php file in each of the public folders. If you want to use artisan to load up the built in php server, you will need to provide `--host` or it will not work. There will be a few limitations on this set up that I have encountered so if someone else knows of a better way I would love to learn how myself.

Comment: Unfortunately I will have zero access to virtualhosts! Wordpress manages to do it without touching it, but who want's to use Wordpress when you can use Laravel?

Comment: Then your situation is actually both simpler and harder at the same time. You set a constant based on $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] that controls what site is loaded and for your conditional checks, routes, etc and you are done for the set up. The hard part is every resource and link must store the full url to know what site it belongs to. If you look in a Wordpress database, every post, image, etc will have the entire url of the domain it belongs with. It will take a lot more discipline to support than it will to set up. You may want to create app/start/multisite.php to organize your code.